# Django using more than 1 package for admin site

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am using 2 django packages: [Admin sortable](https://github.com/alsoicode/django-admin-sortable) (For changing the order of models) and [Django import export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export) (For importing csv directly into my models).

The problem is that if I add the 2 packages into my model admin e.g.

```
class CategoryAdmin(SortableAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
```

they override each other.

[image]

[image]

The buttons either show only for the Admin sortable or the Django import export. Is there anyway I can integrate both of them together? Alternatively, is there another package I can swap out so that I can achieve the same functions (1. change the order of models and 2. import csv directly into models)

Comment: I have the same problem when using admin sortable with import export or reversion. So far, there's no cure, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by [overriding the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories) used on the page. Both Admin Sortable and Django Import Export override the admin change_list.html template in different ways, which is why they don't play nice together.

I used the adminsortable template as my base (Found in `site_packages/adminsortable/templates/adminsortable/change_list_with_sort_link.html`), and added some pieces from the django import export template (Found in `site_packages/import_export/templates/admin/import_export/change_list_import_export.html`) to get this merged template:

```
{% extends change_list_template_extends %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    {% for sorting_filter in sorting_filters %}
    <li>
        <a href="./sort/?sort_filter={{ forloop.counter0 }}">{% trans 'Change Order of' %} {{ sorting_filter }}</a>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>
        <a href="./sort/">{% trans 'Change Order' %}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% include "admin/import_export/change_list_import_item.html" %}
    {% include "admin/import_export/change_list_export_item.html" %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

The lines:

```
{% include "admin/import_export/change_list_import_item.html" %}
{% include "admin/import_export/change_list_export_item.html" %}
```

Add the import export buttons to the template.

Then, you need to tell django to use this template. The [SortableAdminBase](https://github.com/alsoicode/django-admin-sortable/blob/master/adminsortable/admin.py#L26) class has a field called `sortable_change_list_with_sort_link_template` which you can override to use your new custom template. So your admin class will look like:

```
class CategoryAdmin(ImportExportMixin, SortableAdmin):
    sortable_change_list_with_sort_link_template = 'admin/category/change_list_import_export_sortable.html'
```

Assuming you put your custom template in `admin/category/change_list_import_export_sortable.html`

If all works well, you should be getting all 3 buttons appearing at the top of your admin page:
[Django Import Export Admin Sortable Buttons Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7n7J.png)

Comment: This worked for me and I am using django-jet admin. The only thing is SortableAdmin needs to come before the ImportExportMixin. Like this ```class CategoryAdmin(SortableAdmin, ImportExportMixin):``` I also had to add a style to the template to display the buttons in the list using CSS inline-flex.